# Favorite sites show in drawer are limited to first 7 from the list

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, scrolling

When I add several sites to the android app, I cannot scroll through all the sites I have pinned. This happens on both my Moto X and 2013 N7.

It displays all the sites in my list when I tap "Edit", but only shows the first seven of them when looking at the main drawer. Is this limit on purpose? Can it be removed?

Comment: +1, but this is a [feature-request] not a bug.

Comment: Sorry about that... First question!

Comment: This is also not a question about bug reports. It's a feature request asking to add scrolling in the app, now tagged properly. :-)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to do better on subsequent questions.

Comment: This is actually a bug. The left-panel is supposed to be scrollable no matter how many items you put into it. Is there a certain number of sites after which it stops being scrollable for you? Is it scrollable ever? Any more information would be great.

Comment: Let me clarify: the whole panel will scroll, but if I add more than 7 sites to "Your Sites" list, I can't scroll the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an inadvertent limit on the number of sites you can add to your list. By default, if you have no favorite selected, we display the top 7 sites you belong to sorted by your reputation on them. When adding the editing functionality I accidentally left that limit of 7 in, without meaning to. This has been resolved as of version 1.0.8.

Comment: Just updated! Thank you for fixing this!